# Where can i find Oracle.DataAccess.dll?

Tags: database, oracle

Can anyone help me how can i find Oracle.dataAccess.all for Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.4.0?
I try to connect my application with database, but i got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.1.2,
> Culture=neutral' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference. (Exception from RESULT: 0x80131040)

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

By default the Oracle Instant Client does not include the *Oracle Data Provider for .NET*, i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. You must download and install from [ODAC Runtime Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacdeploy-downloads.html)

Note, the provider is very sensitive regarding the version. ODP.NET version 4.112.1.2 (which means 11.2.0.1.2) does not work with Oracle Client 11.2.0.4.0.

They have to match exactly!

Usually it does not make any sense to install an Oracle Instant Client and then add the ODP.NET. Install the needed ODAC from above, the Oracle Instant Client is always included in any Oracle Client installation package.

Comment: This version '4.112.1.2' i have used on my old oracle db. Now i have database on different server, not in the same with my application, i don't have access there, i have only connection string. I download "64-bit ODAC 11.2.0.4.0", what i have to do next ? I don't see any setup file

Comment: Verify that your application is also 64-bit, otherwise it does not work. The zip should contain a `install.bat` and a readme file.